# Stopping std::threads in ROS

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, asyncspinner, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to stop two threads from within a while loop but it doesn't stop on the Ctrl+C (SIGINT).How do I terminate the threads on receiving  Ctrl+C from CLI? Would an `AsyncSpinner` help me here? I do not understand the syntax implementation of `AsyncSpinner`, specifically how to assign a method to a thread spun by it (as I have been able to do with `std::threads` below).

```
void Listener::spin(int sockfd){

int n;
sock_fd_ = sockfd;
ros::Rate loop_rate(MESSAGE_FREQ);      // set the rate as defined in the macro MESSAGE_FREQ

while(ros::ok) {          

    loop_rate.sleep();

    std::thread t_write(&Listener::getMessageValue, this); //writes data onto tcp socket
    std::thread t_read(&Listener::readBuffer, this);  // reads data from tcp socket

    t_write.join();
    t_read.join();        
    
    ros::spinOnce();
        
   }  

   n = close(sock_fd_);
         
}
```

This is being called in the main like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     .... 
    listener.spin(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316028/stopping-std::threads-in-ros/) by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2019-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If `getMessageValue` or `readBuffer` have a never ending loop, the program will never pass the call to `.join()`, because there it waits for the threads to finish. If this is the case, the easiest solution *might* be to call `.detach()` instead of `.join()`.

However, if the two thread functions are just message callbacks, you should indeed use the `AsyncSpinner`.

> specifically how to assign a method to a thread spun by it

You do not have to manually assign a method here, this is done by registering the callbacks when subscribing to a topic. The `AsyncSpinner` then lets the number of threads you specified execute those callbacks.
Surely you already saw the [Wiki entry on callbacks](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning), but it really explains how to do it.

---

Originally posted by [cellard0or](https://answers.ros.org/users/27123/cellard0or/) with karma: 61 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0